# Given that a divides b, what transformation can I do to a, to be sure it doesn't divide b anymore?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Suppose that all I know is that $ b \% a = 0$, so that $a$ divides $b$.

I want to transform $a$ in a way that I am sure it will not divide $b$, for any pair of numbers $a$ and $b$.

Is there such a transformation?

I thought just subtracting a number could suffice, but that obviously doesn't work. For instance $3$ divides $12$ but also $2$ divides $12$.

Any ideas?

**Without making a larger than b obviously..**

Comment: One idea that I had was to consider $c = \frac{b}{a}$. We don't know whether $a$ divides $b$ only or if other powers of $a$ divide $b$. However we could still evaluate $d = \frac{c}{a}$. If $a==b$ then this is $0$. If only $a^1$ divides $b$ then this is a floating point, while if other powers of $a$ divide $b$, then this is an integer..

Comment: How about the transformation that sends every $a$ to $0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A universal transformation (not depending on $b$) cannot exist, simply because $b$ can always be divisible by both $a$ and the transformed $a$ , let us denote it with $f(a)$. Just choose $b=a\cdot f(a)$ to see this.

The expression $b-a+1$ does the job, if we assume $1<a<b$. So, we have to assume that $a$ is a non-trivial divisor of $b$ (neither $1$ nor $b$)

Proof that not both $a$ and $b-a+1$ can divide $b$ : We assume that both $a$ and $b-a+1$ divide $b$. Then, there is a positive integer $m$ with $m(b-a+1)=b$ since $b-a+1$ must be positive. This implies $$(m-1)b=(a-1)m$$ and therefore $$\frac{b}{a-1}=\frac{m}{m-1}$$ because the (forbidden) case $m=1$ would imply $a=1$ contradicting our assumption. The right side at most $2$ which can be easily seen, but the left side is larger than $\frac{b}{a}$, which itself is at least $2$. We get a contradiction, hence we have proven that $b-a+1$ does the job.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding, but I meant that, given $a$ and $b$, then $b$ is fixed. So we can choose any pair, but once we have chosen it, we can't change $b$

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't see "not depending on $b$"

Comment: Would you be able to provide a proof? I will accept it for that!

Comment: @Euler_Salter For the first or the second part ?

Comment: For the second part!

Comment: @Euler_Salter I have slightly changed my expression. This expression does the job whenever $a$ is a non-trivial divisor of $b$ (See answer)

Comment: The original expression did not work in all cases.